# Sum values having same ID

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

Hi Guys this is my Table called "W". I would like to sum the values having the same TID :

```
REF  |   W_Date   |  W_MK |   TID   |   Value   |
===============================================
1   | 2012-12-11 |   1   |   112   |   30      |
2   | 2012-12-11 |   2   |   112   |   3       |
3   | 2012-12-11 |   1   |   113   |   22      |
4   | 2012-12-11 |   3   |   114   |   2       |
```

This should be my expected result: sum of column "Value" with the same T_ID:

```
W_Date     | TID   | sum(Value)|
===============================
2012-12-11 | 112   |   33      |
2012-12-11 | 113   |   22      |
2012-12-11 | 114   |   2       |
```

Can you help me please ?

Comment: Have you not tried anything?

Comment: I tired this : 
select W_Date, TID, sum(Value)
from W
group by W_Date, TID

Comment: What was wrong about your attempt?

Comment: It is not showing the exact result, not the right calculation

Comment: You were summing over W_Date *and* TID, did you try removing the W_Date from the group by and the select?

Comment: I need to display the date as well

Comment: Then what *exactly* was wrong with your query?

Comment: oh sorry i see , i was running a different query by mistake. thanks !

Comment: Oracle or MySQL? Please tag only the RDBMS you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT W_Date, TID, sum(Value) FROM W
GROUP BY W_Date, TID
```

Answer (score 0):

You need use `SUM` and `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT W_Date,TID,SUM(Value) 
FROM W
GROUP BY W_Date,TID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the SELECT below:

```
SELECT MAX(W_Date) AS W_Date, TID, SUM(Value) AS Value FROM W GROUP BY TID
```

Please, observe that W_Date is not a member of my GROUP BY, so you need to add MAX in his column.